# Pandasql: Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER

Tags: python, pandas, pandasql

I'm getting the following 'Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER' error when I run my code.  I'm a beginner with psql.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
import pandasql as psql
from pandasql import sqldf

T900_file = r'K:\myfile.xlsx'
df1 = pd.read_excel(T900_file)

T1000 = psql.sqldf("""Select Date
                            ,UP_Cust_Num
                            ,UP_Cust_Name
                            ,sum(Utilized_FVO)  as FVO
                            ,avg(UP_Generation) as UP_Gen
                      from df1
                      Group by Date, UP_Cust_Num, UP_Cust_Name""")
```

Error has to be with aggregation. how do i resolve the error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the datatype in df1. If you run

```
df1.info()
```

you will probably see that some numeric values are type `Int64`; if that is the case then you can cast those values to a smaller integers (providing the values fit in the new data type). In order to cast to smaller integers you may need to do something like this:

```
df1["Utilized_FVO"] = df["Utilized_FVO"].astype(np.int8)
df1["UP_Generation"] = df["UP_Generation"].astype(np.int8)
```

Comment: Did a df1['Utilized_FVO'].dtypes , and df1['UP_Generation'].dtypes both came back as dtype('float64')

Comment: I think there may be additional issues here, I removed 'sum(Utilized_FVO)  as FVO' and 'avg(UP_Generation) as UP_Gen' lines from the query.  Still got same error.

Comment: what type is UP_cust_num?

Comment: it's dtype('O')

Comment: Could you please post a sample of the dataframe and the df1.info() result?. I'll try to reproduce the issue to see what is causing it

Comment: I'm not able to post a sample of the dataframe, as it contains client information.  You are correct it is a data issue.  I was able to get past the issue, by saving the excel file as .csv and reading it into pandas via read_csv.

Answer (score 0):

I think it means that you have an overflow error, so it brokes the boundary of an int.